# How to create a global variable in WSO2 ESB - must be updatable

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I've written an ESB resource which takes in a list of test cases, like the example below:

```html
{
    "tests": [
          { "type": "DSS", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "ESB", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "GREG", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "GW", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "MB", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "ID", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" },
          { "type": "BOGUS", "url": "http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test" }
 ]
}
```

The resource takes this in as a JSON array and loops through the elements using the XPATH expression `//tests/type` and generates a status message (`200` if it can do anything, `ERR` if not).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to incrementally add the types into some sort of a global array property which would eventually become `[DSS, ESB, GREG, GW, MB, ID, BOGUS]` so I can write a script to run through this and produce a payload to return something like the below:

```html
{
  "results": [
    { "TYPE": "DSS", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "ESB", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "GREG", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "GW", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "MB", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "ID", "STATUS": "200" },
    { "TYPE": "BOGUS", "STATUS": "ERR" }
  ]
}
```

I've been searching for a way to do this for a couple of days now, to no avail so if it's simply not possible or if I've just been looking for the wrong thing, I don't know but I'd really like to avoid producing a static resource, enabling future expansion with minimal involvement for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your payload in the gov registry with this script :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
  importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
  mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("gov:/trunk/Test/TestTypes",false);
  mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("gov:/trunk/Test/TestTypes",mc.getPayloadXML().toString());
]]></script>
```

- newResource create the resource if it does not exist
- you can use
  mc.getPayloadJSON() instead of mc.getPayloadXML()

A sample with a resource 'TESTSOF' like this :

```
<root>
<value><child>1</child></value>
<value><child>2</child></value>
<value><child>3</child></value>
</root>
```

You can iter all "value" with :

```
<property name="TESTSOF" expression="get-property('registry','gov:/trunk/TESTSOF')" type="OM"/>
<iterate continueParent="true" sequential="false" preservePayload="false" expression="$ctx:TESTSOF//value">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

A sample with JSON : 
Load JSON as the current message :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('registry','gov:/trunk/Test/TestTypes')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Iterate :

```
<iterate continueParent="true" sequential="false" preservePayload="false" expression="//tests">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

Comment: Nice one.  Was looking forward to figuring my way through writing a script for it but yours is probably infinitely more elegant than mine would have ended up being!